# Which Stack Exchange site is appropriate for asking for an email replacement service?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Where can I ask this kind of question?

> I often exchange emails that are one line long (like a
>   Facebook/WhatsApp) chat message. The answer I get is also very short,
>   and the email exhange goes on for 20- 50 messages.
>
> Email is not the best format for this kind of message exchange, but I
>   have to use it anyway. I'd like a plugin for Chrome or some other
>   software to visualize the various emails as if they were chat message,
>   without any header.

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for a telephone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're asking for a piece of software, so it would be [Software recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/).

Make sure you adhere to the rules of that site, which are quite different from Stack Overflow.

Comment: **[What is required for a question to contain “enough information”? (meta.softwarerecs.se)](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information)**